# Mutable state of value from viewModel is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a `mutablestate` in my `ViewModel` that I'm trying to set and access in my composable. When I use delegated Property of `remember` it is working but after creating it in viewModel and accessing it in compose the state of the variable is empty how to use the state with viewModel

Everything is working fine when the state is inside the compose

```
var mSelectedText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
```

But when i use it from viewModel change and set my OutlinedTextField value = mainCatTitle and onValueChange = {mainCatTitle = it} the selected title is not Showing up in the OutlinedTextField is empty

```
 private val _mainCatTitle = mutableStateOf("")
 val mainCatTitle: State<String> = _mainCatTitle
```

my Composable

```
   var mSelectedText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   var mainCatTitle = viewModel.mainCatTitle.value

   Column(Modifier.padding(20.dp)) {

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = mainCatTitle,
        onValueChange = { mainCatTitle = it },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                mTextFieldSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
            },
        readOnly = true,
        label = { Text(text = "Select MainCategory") },
        trailingIcon = {
            Icon(icon, "contentDescription",
                Modifier.clickable { mExpanded = !mExpanded })
        }
    )

    DropdownMenu(expanded = mExpanded,
        onDismissRequest = { mExpanded = false },
        modifier = Modifier.width(with(
            LocalDensity.current) {
            mTextFieldSize.width.toDp()
        })) {
        selectCategory.forEach {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                mainCatTitle = it.category_name.toString()
                mSelectedCategoryId = it.category_id.toString()
                mExpanded = false
                Log.i(TAG,"Before the CategoryName: $mainCatTitle " )
            }) {

                Text(text = it.category_name.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}

Log.i(TAG,"Getting the CategoryName: $mainCatTitle " )
}
```

in my First log inside the DropDownMenuItem the log is showing the Selected field but second log is empty

Have attached the image
[image]

Comment: How do you update it in your ViewModel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your'e directly modifying the `mainCatTitle` variable from `onClick`, not the state hoisted by your `ViewMoel`

```
  DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
        mainCatTitle = it.category_name.toString()
        ...
```

and because you didn't provide anything about your `ViewModel`, I would assume and suggest to create a function if you don't have one in your `ViewModel` that you can call like this,

```
DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
       viewModel.onSelectedItem(it) // <-- this function
       ...
}
```

and in your `ViewModel` you update the state like this

```
fun onSelectedItem(item: String) { // <-- this is the function
    _mainCatTitle.value = item
}
```